# Swift - Alamofire Post, change image if true

Tags: swift, alamofire

I added a "fav button" to my cell, and I want to change the icon if the faved. I know what I need to do but I dont know how,

I need to create a func to post a Alamofire request when "fav button" pressed.
then when I load reload the page, I need to check if the "fav button" pressed and change the icon inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. How am I implement these?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

a) You can wait for the POST response, optionally using a placeholder image while the request is in progress, and put the right image when the response arrives.

b) You can use an "optimistic" approach, setting the hopefully right image (if POST request is successfully completed), and then adjust the image according to the response when it arrives.

There are plenty of examples even in Alamofire documentation about making POST requests. But you must bear in mind that for the same cell you can have multiple requests (when scrolling your cells are reused), so be aware of the cell you update has to match the item faved.

The best thing you can do is to update your model on response arrival (generally this is what a POST means), and fire a view (cell) update after that. At this point you should be using some ovserver/observable mechanism in order to identify which cell to reload (don't do a full table reload for just a fav).